# Build a PHP array out of a foreach loop based on a count

Tags: php

I'm using PayPal's `_cart` form to take payment on a site I am building. I'm then using the `notify_url` to post the submitted fields to a PHP page that will in turn use the SendGrid API to send a confirmation email. This all works fine, but what I am wanting to do is create an 'order summary' of the items purchased (which can be multiple).

```
foreach ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['num_cart_items']; $i++) {
   $name = $_POST['item_name' . $i];
   $number = $_POST['item_number' . $i];
   $quantity = $_POST['quantity' . $i];
}
```

What I am wanting to do is build an array out of the above so I can use `$cart as $order`, for example. Is it possible to make the above foreach build into an array?

Comment: Yes, you just push each value on to a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$cart = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['num_cart_items']; $i++) {
   $name = $_POST['item_name' . $i];
   $number = $_POST['item_number' . $i];
   $quantity = $_POST['quantity' . $i];
   $cart[] = [
       'name'    => $name,
       'number'  => $number,
       'quantity'=> quantity
       // you can add more 'key'=>$value pairs here
   ];
}
```

Now you can do `foreach($cart as $order) { ... }` where `$order` is the array containing the above keys